# How to display an OptionsetField with default checked value

Tags: silverstripe

I was checking previous questions but I couldn't find any answer for this. For example I have a field called Gender with 2 selections. How can I set male as selected by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a "Value" in the constructor for setting the default "key".
http://api.silverstripe.org/3/OptionsetField.html#method___construct

```
$field = new OptionsetField(
    $name = 'Optionfield', 
    $title = 'My Option Field',
    $source = array(
        'Option1' => 'Value1',
        'Option2' => 'Value2'
    ), 
    $default = 'Option1'
)
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the quick response! I found another way which is to use the setValue($value) method after creating the OptionsetField object. In fact, the setValue() seems to work in other FormField objects as well. Cheers!

Comment: Would you mind adding a short code example, as "link only" answers are seemed as low quality on StackOverflow